# How to detect that internal hard disk is removed and which files were copied?

Tags: security, data, hardware

Its easy to steal internal hdd, which do not generate sound signals to aware the owner while removing and allows Thief to copy the data.

Is there any way by which these thieves acts can be traced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Encrypt the entire harddisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption), then the copied data is useless.

But if someone malicious has unrestricted access to your hardware, you have lost the security game anyway. They can install all kinds of spyware or even hardware bugs. Then the encryption will not help you either. See [Evil Maid Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack).

Securing your hardware is the first and most basic layer of security. If you cannot do that, everything else is somewhat pointless.

Comment: One case example. All drives encrypted. Will it work, when one drive is opened for working and laptop is in lock (Win+L) mode. Owner is away from laptop.

Comment: @M.Patil: If an attacker simply removes the harddisk, it is still encrypted and thus useless. "Opening" it just means the OS knows the encryption key. In theory, it might be possible to read the key from the memory of the OS even if it's locked, but that would require *very* sophisticated equipment and expertise, and a lot of time working on the running system.